# laravel eloquent and EAV

Tags: laravel, database-design, eloquent, laravel-query-builder, entity-attribute-value

Implementing E-Commerce using laravel 6 , the eav model used to capture the products attributes as following ;

The question is how to get the Product Attribute (colors) Value of Specific product (ex:productno3) the current implementation get ALL the attribute (color) Values . we need the (ex:productno3) colors only.

[image: database schema]

each table data as following :

[image: products]
[image: attributes]
[image: products_attributes]
[image: value]
[image: products_attributes_values]

## The Product model

```
class Product extends Model{

protected $fillable = ['name', 'brand', 'price', 'description', 'image_name'];

public function category(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
}


public function attributes(){

    return $this->belongsToMany(Attribute::class,'products__attributes')->withTimestamps();
}   }
```

## Attribute model

```
class Attribute extends Model{

public function products(){

    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class,'products__attributes')->withTimestamps();
}



public function values()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Value::class);
}}
```

## Value model

```
class Value extends Model{

public function attribute()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Attribute::class);
}




public function productattributevalue()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Attribute::class,'products_attributes_values');

}}
```

## ProductController

```
class ProductController extends Controller{   

public function index()
{
    // we need to get the productno3 colors from table ( products_attributes_values )
    $product_no3 = Product::find(3)->attributes()->first()->values;dd($product_no3);}}
```

> How to get the Product Attribute (colors) Value of Specific product (ex:productno3) the current implementation get ALL the attribute (color) Values . we need the (ex:productno3) colors only.it should be only red and blue for productno3 .

[image: dd($product_no3);]

[image]

> it should be only red and blue for productno3 .

[image]

THE SQL dump is here at this link : [SQL DUMP](https://gofile.io/?c=Lg0xxN)

Comment: Your data model seems redundant, why does values have an attribute id?, thats the reason why you get 3 results.

Comment: Why do you have the product_values and products_attributes_values, you could have a table 'products_attributes' and save the product_id, attribute_id and value in there. Now you are overcomplicating your tables. Also, why not use the attribute type as its ID, instead of an incrementing ID. I'm assuming you're not going to define the 'color' attribute twice.

Comment: @mrhn we have attribute (color ) and attribute(size) we could also have more attributes later ( such as : material : wood - plastic etc ) for that reason for each attribute i need to know the value of it !

Comment: This seems overly complex

Comment: @mrhn do you have any alternative ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have 2 tables products_attributes, attributes and and there is an attribute 'color'.

### Laravel query builder

```
 $users = DB::table('products_attributes')
      ->join('attributes', 'products_attributes.attribute_id', '=', 'attributes.id')
      ->select('attributes.color')
      ->get();
```

> I think it is possible to solve this joining 2 tables.